# writting to disk is taking more time in solaris

Tags: solaris

writing in disk taking more time, application is not working properly due to this delay in disk on solaris machine.
how to find out the disk(md500) is faulty or anything problem with disk

```
$  iostat -em
           ---- errors --- 
device   s/w h/w trn tot 
lofi126    0   0   0   0 
md200      0   0   0   0 
md201      0   0   0   0 
md202      0   0   0   0 
md210      0   0   0   0 
md211      0   0   0   0 
md212      0   0   0   0 
md230      0   0   0   0 
md231      0   0   0   0 
md232      0   0   0   0 
md240      0   0   0   0 
md241      0   0   0   0 
md242      0   0   0   0 
md250      0   0   0   0 
md251      0   0   0   0 
md252      0   0   0   0 
md260      0   0   0   0 
md261      0   0   0   0 
md262      0   0   0   0 
md400      0   0   0   0 
md401      0   0   0   0 
md402      0   0   0   0 
md403      0   0   0   0 
md404      0   0   0   0 
md405      0   0   0   0 
md500      0   0   0   0 
sd0        0   0   0   0 
sd1        0   0   0   0 
sd2        0   0   0   0 
sd3        0   0   0   0 
sd4        0   0   0   0 
sd5        0   0   0   0 
sd6        0   0   0   0 
sd7        0   0   0   0 
sd8        0   0   0   0 
sd15       0   1   0   1 
sd16       0   0   0   0 
sd17       0   0   0   0 
sd18       0   0   0   0 
sd19       0   0   0   0 
sd20       0   0   0   0 
sd21       0   0   0   0 
sd22       0   0   0   0 
sd25       0   0   0   0 
sd26       0   0   0   0 
sd27       0   0   0   0 
sd28       0   0   0   0 
sd29       0   0  58  58 
nfs1       0   0   0   0
```

.

```
$ iostat -xtc
                 extended device statistics                     tty         cpu
device     r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv  svc_t  %w  %b  tin tout  us sy wt id
lofi126    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    7.6   0   0    0  406  23 11  0 66
md200      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0   17.8   0   0 
md201      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    8.5   0   0 
md202      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0   16.4   0   0 
md210      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    6.0   0   0 
md211      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    5.1   0   0 
md212      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    7.0   0   0 
md230      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0   12.5   0   0 
md231      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0   17.3   0   0 
md232      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0   16.6   0   0 
md240      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
md241      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
md242      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
md250      1.0    0.9   13.2    2.5  0.0  0.0    9.7   0   0 
md251      0.5    0.9    6.6    2.5  0.0  0.0    7.9   0   0 
md252      0.5    0.9    6.6    2.5  0.0  0.0    9.4   0   0 
md260      1.1    1.2   32.7    4.0  0.0  0.0    8.5   0   1 
md261      0.5    1.2   16.4    4.0  0.0  0.0    6.2   0   1 
md262      0.5    1.2   16.3    4.0  0.0  0.0    7.0   0   1 
md400     10.1   15.1  209.3  160.6  0.0  0.8   32.1   1   9 
md401      5.1   15.1  104.7  160.6  0.0  0.7   32.2   0   7 
md402      5.1   15.1  104.6  160.6  0.0  0.7   32.7   0   7 
md403      0.7    0.8   27.3    7.7  0.0  0.0    9.2   0   1 
md404      0.1    0.0    2.2    0.0  0.0  0.0    2.5   0   0 
md405      9.4   14.0  179.8  148.9  0.0  0.8   33.8   0   8 
md500      6.7  278.3  101.4 4065.8  0.0  0.3    1.2   0   8 
sd0        0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd1        1.5    2.2   23.2    6.5  0.0  0.0    6.1   0   1 
sd2        1.4    4.7   23.1    7.8  0.0  0.1    8.8   0   3 
sd3        5.3   15.2  104.8  160.6  0.4  0.3   31.6   1   7 
sd4        5.3   15.2  104.7  160.6  0.4  0.3   32.2   1   7 
sd5        0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd6        0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd7        0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd8        0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd15       3.9   18.3   62.7  245.9  0.0  0.0    0.6   0   1 
sd16       3.4   18.3   62.4  246.1  0.0  0.0    0.6   0   1 
sd17       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd18       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd19       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd20       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd21       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd22       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd25       3.5   18.2   63.2  245.9  0.0  0.1    3.6   0   6 
sd26       3.4   18.2   63.2  246.1  0.0  0.1    3.5   0   6 
sd27       6.7  278.1  101.3 4063.1  0.1  0.2    1.1   0   8 
sd28       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
sd29       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0 
nfs1       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `metastat -p` and add the output of what disks make up md500 to your question

Comment: Also is there anything in `/var/adm/messages` that stands out?

Comment: there is no error /var/adm/messages
$ metastat -p 
bash: metastat: command not found

Comment: it should be in `/usr/sbin`, also is this a non global zone?

Comment: Long shot, but check the directory size of /tmp -- for some reason, too many files in /tmp slows down everything, including file writes (even those outside /tmp)